# How get a binary matrix according a condition to each its row

Tags: r

I have a vector of integers.And I need to construct a binary matrix which depend on this vectors.In fact,I want to get for each line of matrix zeros just the column which its index equal 
to the w value.
This is an example :

```
w=c(2,3,5,4)
nr=length(w)
M=matrix(1*nr*length(w),nrow=nr,ncol=max(w))
```

the result should be like that for this example:

```
01000
00100
00001
00010
```

so I run this code but i didn't get the result shown belown:

```
for ( i in 1:nr)
{ 
for(j in 1:max(w))
{ if(w[j]==j)
  M[i,j]=1
else
  M[i,j]=0
}
}
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Might be useful to add the results you're getting with that code. Also adding tags like 'vector' or 'matrix' will help get you more visibility. Welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a matrix with all 0 and then replace those cells to be 1.

```
w <- c(2, 3, 5, 4)
nr <- length(w)
M <- matrix(0, nrow = nr, ncol = max(w))

for (i in 1:nr){
  M[i, w[i]] <- 1
}

M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
`[<-`(matrix(0,nrow=length(w),ncol=max(w)),cbind(seq_along(w),w),1)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
```